# What is the most recommended SLAM package to use on MRS1xxx LiDAR?

Tags: slam, navigation, ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to be able to use SLAM to map an area, save the map with the capability of restoring it at anytime, and ultimately tell my robot (which contains encoder-based servo motors ) to drive to a specific location in the map itself.

I previously tampered with a turtlebot3 and its SLAM capabilities, and i was wondering if there exists a package that best offers these functionalities for the LiDAR.

I'm relatively new to ROS; thus, there might be some terminologies that i may be unaware of. However, thanks to the ease of use of this wonderful framework, i been learning pretty quickly.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/296431/what-is-the-most-recommended-slam-package-to-use-on-mrs1xxx-lidar?/) by [chrisfernam2](https://answers.ros.org/users/36263/chrisfernam2/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2018-07-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

http://wiki.ros.org/navigation/Tutorials

There are multiple packages you can use but since you have encoders and Lidar, I recommend Navigation Stack. It will do just what you're wanting and has an excellent tutorial that accommodates a beginner.

---

Originally posted by [billy](https://answers.ros.org/users/26871/billy/) with karma: 1850 on 2018-07-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0